# Passing over Object between Classes not working

Tags: objective-c, memory, object

hey guys,
i'm new to objective-c and i'm having trouble with the memory management. i declared 3 classes, Table, Dataset and my Main class. In my mainclass, i created an Dataset Object and now im trying to pass this Object over to a Tableobject, where i want to store it permanently. but it seems to me that the garbage collector kills the reference before i can use it.

heres some code:

Dataset:

```
    //Dataset.h
@interface Dataset : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray* daten; 
}

@end

//Dataset.m
#import "Dataset.h"
#import "Datensatz.h"

@implementation Dataset


- (id) init
{
    self=[super init];
    daten=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}
```

Table:

```
//Table.h

@class Dataset;

@interface Table : NSObject {
    Dataset* daten;
}
-(id)init:(NSTableView *)aTableView;
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex;
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView;
@property (retain) Dataset* daten;

@end

//Table.m

#import "Table.h"
#import "Dataset.h"
@impl

ementation Table

    @synthesize daten;

    -(id)init:(NSTableView*)aTableView
    {
        self=[super init];
        [self setDaten:[Datenmenge alloc]];
        return self;
    }
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    NSLog(@"anzahl: %d %@",[self.daten anzahl], self.daten);//This is always 0 null
    return [daten anzahl];

}
    -(void)setDaten:(Dataset *)a
    {
        NSLog(@"setter: anzahl: %d %@",[a anzahl], a);
        [daten release];
        daten=[a retain];
        NSLog(@"setter: anzahl: %d %@",[daten anzahl], daten);
    }
    @end
```

In my mainclass i do the following:

```
  //init method
    [self setDaten:[[[Dataset alloc]init]autorelease]];
    tabelle=[[Table alloc] init:tableview];
    [tabelle setDaten:[self daten]];
```

Mainclass:

```
//code.h
//
//  MalWiederWasNeuesAppDelegate.h
//  MalWiederWasNeues
//
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class Datenmenge,Graph,Tabelle;

@interface MalWiederWasNeuesAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    NSToolbarItem *datenKnopf;
    NSToolbarItem *speichernKnopf;
    NSSlider *scaleSlider;
    NSScroller *moveSlider;
    NSTableView* tableview;
    Graph* graph;
    Tabelle* tabelle;
    Datenmenge* daten;

}

-(void)tuWas;

- (IBAction)datenHinzufuegen:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)speichern:(id)sender;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSToolbarItem *datenKnopf;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSToolbarItem *speichernKnopf;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSSlider *scaleSlider;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSScroller *moveSlider;
@property (assign) IBOutlet Graph *graph;
@property (assign) IBOutlet Tabelle *tabelle;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView* tableview;
@property (retain) Datenmenge* daten;
@end

//code.m
//
//  MalWiederWasNeuesAppDelegate.m
//  MalWiederWasNeues
//
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MalWiederWasNeuesAppDelegate.h"
#import "Datenmenge.h"
#import "Graph.h"
#import "Tabelle.h"
@implementation MalWiederWasNeuesAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize daten;
-(id) init
{
    self.daten=[[Datenmenge alloc]init];
    [self.daten datenHinzufuegen:nil];
    tabelle=[[Tabelle alloc] init:tableview];
    tabelle.daten=daten;

    NSLog(@"konstruktor: %f %d",[daten maximum],[daten anzahl]);
    //graph.daten=daten;

    return self;
}

-(void)tuWas{

}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application 
}

- (IBAction)datenHinzufuegen:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%f %d",[daten maximum],[daten anzahl]);
    NSLog(@"daten hinzufügen");
}

- (IBAction) speichern:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %@",daten,[tabelle daten]);
    NSLog(@"speichern");    
}

@end
```

I hope this wasnt too much code for you.
when i call a method of "tabelle", my Table object, "daten" does not refer to an Dataset Object. But the NSLogs in "setDaten" show me valid references.
so, what am i doing wrong?

have a good evening,
lukas

Answer (score 1):

You define Daten as a retain type

`@property (retain) Dataset* daten;` and `@synthesize daten;`

theres no need to then implement the method

`-(void)setDaten:(Dataset *)a` thats what `@synthesize daten;` does

I think theres a lost in translation moment here so ill assume Table == Tabelle and Dataset == Datmenge and I dont see the implementation for your main class.

cast your eye over this too.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

Comment: removing my own setDaten method doesnt change the behaviour, i think it basically does the same thing a setter generated with @synthesize would do + logging..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the daten property of your main class is declared as `assign`? In that case daten is correct when you call `setDaten:`, but might have been already autoreleased when you try to access it afterwards.

Also,

```
-(void)setDaten:(Dataset *)a
{
    NSLog(@"setter: anzahl: %d %@",[a anzahl], a);
    [daten release];
    daten=[a retain];
    NSLog(@"setter: anzahl: %d %@",[daten anzahl], daten);
}
```

is not a good implementation of a setter. If a == daten, then this object will be released (and maybe dealloc'd). You need to check identity of objects when implementing your own setter.

Comment: hm, my main class is connected to a window with buttons. for testing, when i push a button, i print the Dataset object and its always there. so i dont think it is released early. since i dont call the setter twice i dont think the identity check is a problem

Comment: Ok, then what else do you do with your tabelle object between `setDaten` and calling method, which shows that daten in tabelle is an incorrect reference? Maybe you release tabelle, or nil daten in tabelle? BTW, the code you pasted above is REALLY incomplete, so one can only guess what your problem is :)

Comment: i really didnt want to paste all the code, but okay. ill give you some context: The Table Class is giving an NSTableView the data to show. this data should be read in the dataset object, but when the nstableview calls numberOfRowsInTableView the Table Object does not know a Dataset Object and my TableView is empty.

Comment: Seems like you're doing `tabelle.daten = nil;` somewhere in your code. I have no other explanation why tabelle is valid while tabelle->daten is referenced to nil. That's my last guess, sorry :(

Comment: okay, the tabelle object is created with interface builder, maybe theres a problem

Comment: figured it out. in my main class, i should have written all my code into the applicationfinishedlaunching method. the problem was that i initialized a Table object, but soon after, the Table object i created in interface designer, was created too overwriting the one i used for setting the dataset... stupid mistake took me hours to debug -.-, but now i can go to bed :D